# SQL - Combining multiple like queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hey my first question on SO! Anywho...

Still relatively a newb at SQL so I think I might be missing something here. My question is I currently have a table full of phone numbers. I want to have a query where I search for phone numbers that are similar to a list I have. So for example, I want to find phone numbers that begin with '555123', '555321', and '555987'. I know normally if you have a list of numbers you could just do a query such as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM phonenumbers 
 WHERE number in ('5551234567', '5559876543', .... );
```

Is there a way to do this with like? Such as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM phonenumbers 
 WHERE number in like ('555123%', '555321%', '555987%'); //I know this doesn't actually work
```

Instead of have to do this individually

```
SELECT * 
  FROM phonenumbers 
 WHERE number like '555123%' 
    or number like '555321%' 
    or number like '555987%'; //Which does work but takes a long time
```

Or is there an easier to do this that I'm just missing? I'm using postgres, I don't know if there's any commands it has that would help out with that. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've retagged your question to clarify it relates to postgres

Comment: What version of Postgres?  Sounds like a job for regexes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: `Which does work but takes a long time` - unless you change the nature of the query, a different syntactic representation of the same thing will take as long. Is the column indexed?

Comment: Actually the column is indexed. I hadn't noticed that before. Oh, and I am using postgres 8.0. I have a large amount of numbers I am searching.

Comment: How long does your query take? How many records you have in your table?

Comment: Your query will result in an index search and as many comparisons for each item as you have conditions in your `where` clause. If you need these queries to be faster, you need to introduce an index that is more suited to your type of query.

Comment: Hmm I just realized that there is another cron running on the system that is currently inserting records into this table, which is no doubt impacting my query performance. I'll have to try some of these searches after that it is done (it's taking 5+ minutes to return results for my queries). Darn crons running at inconvenient times ;)

Comment: As for how many records, it's not actually a table of specifically numbers but calls with the numbers and other such data. So it's like in the millions. (sorry for the double post)

Comment: transfer the data in a holding table, for temporary use, and try queries on it (that will be the true benchmark as won't be affected by reads and locks of any running connection)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use `SIMILAR TO` and separate the tags with | pipe `'555123%|555321%|555987%'`

eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM phonenumbers 
WHERE number SIMILAR TO '555123%|555321%|555987%'
```

Answer (score 41):

Late to the party, but for posterity... You can also use a [ANY(array expression)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486)

```
SELECT * 
FROM phonenumbers 
WHERE number LIKE ANY(ARRAY['555123%', '555321%', '555987%'])
```

Comment: FWIW there's also a "LIKE ALL(...)" option https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742019/32453

Answer (score 7):

Assuming all your numbers do not contain letters, and your numbers are always "prefixes" (ex: `LIKE '123%'`):

```
SELECT  number
FROM    (
        VALUES
        ('555123'),
        ('555321'),
        ('555000')
        ) prefixes (prefix)
JOIN    phonenumbers
ON      number >= prefix
        AND number < prefix || 'a'
```

This will use an index on `phonenumbers`, if any, so could be faster.

Comment: Do you have a blog or intentions to write a book about these? I would be among the buyers.

Comment: @Pentium10: http://explainextended.com The book is in progress, but this is a secret yet, please don't tell anybody.

Answer (score 4):

You can also rely on POSIX regular expressions, see section 9.7.3 of the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html).

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE name ~ '12345|34567';
```

It is important to note that your `name` field is of a string type.

Comment: Not sure why but this solution was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, but you could join `phonenumbers` on a table `criteria` containing the values you want to match on, i.e.

```
JOIN criteria ON phonenumbers.number LIKE criteria.phonenumbers
```

...probably not worth it for a small number of conditions, though

Comment: Actually I do have a lot more to search but thought I should keep it simple with just a few numbers.

Comment: or create temp table.  Probably won't be any speedup from other options but an option whoa.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if your prefixes are all the same length then you can do `where RIGHT(number) in ('123456', '234456', 'etc', 'etc')`