# LIKE clause vs. IN clause--which is better?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Which one is better using condition in where statement or in join statement?
Can anyone please help?

Comment: The Title and the question seems different.
Can you please take a look?

Comment: If going off the title, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Any condition that prevents the a SQL server optimizer to use an index it's bad condition.

If in your case `in` or `like` operator is better that says the query plan only.

Typically a "%" wildcard at the beginning of the string prevents the SQL Server to use an index. Sometimes a `in` operator prevents to use an index.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement to to filter the rows by a known set of fixed values then **where x in (a, b, c, ...)** will work better than **where x like 'g'** because it may not be possible to create a suitable like clause.

If the requirement is to filter by a prefix then **where x like 'prefix%'** will work better than **where x in (a, b, c, ...)** because it might not be possible to create an in() clause that is correct.