# How do I search "many LIKE" in the database (mysql)?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to search number of strings in the Database (type: MYSQL) and I did this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `rooms` 
 WHERE `dates` LIKE '%09/08/10%' OR '%08/08/10%'
```

Why doesnt it work? when I removed the part of `OR '%08/08/10%'` it was working well, I think I use it not good. 
How should I do it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ... 
FROM rooms 
WHERE dates LIKE '%09/08/10%' 
  Or dates LIKE '%08/08/10%'
```

Comment: There is a simple way than this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Luis - As far as I know, there is no simpler means to do a series of wildcard searches. If you wanted an exact match, that would be different.

Comment: You can also try ` WHERE dates REGEXP "0(9|8)/08/10"` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms 
WHERE 
      dates LIKE '%09/08/10%' 
      OR 
      dates LIKE '%08/08/10%'
```