# MySQL, Finding words from one string in another string

Tags: sql, mysql

I have no idea if this is possible to do in one SQL statement. I have been reading all day and can't seem to find a solution and to be frank, my experience is only at the tip of the iceberg when it comes to SQL.

I have two different tables, lets say: items and customers.
Both tables have a field (Notes) of type TEXT containing words separated with spaces and CR/LF pairs.

I need to select all rows (items.*) where any of the words in customers.note matches any word in items.note

Example:

```
Table items
ID NOTES
-- ----------
1  bag candle fork
2  max kielland
3  plate knife fork
4  wheel brownbag

Table customers
ID NOTES
-- ----------
1  brown candle fork
```

The result I want would be:

```
Items.ID Items.Note
-------- ----------
1        bag candle fork
3        plate knife fork
```

I have been looking at IN and LIKE (as separate solutions, not together as a pair) but they don't seem to quite solve the problem.
If it is to any help, I can make sure all spaces are replaced by ','

In the long end it would be even more perfect if the compare could be made as the LIKE %..% producing a result like this:

```
Items.ID Items.Note
-------- ----------
1        bag candle fork
3        plate knife fork
4        wheel brownbag
```

as you can see the brown get a hit on brownbag.

As I said I don't know if this is possible in MySQL without splitting up the query in several questions with some PHP processing.

Thank you.

---

### Update

With the help of OMG Ponies MATCH..AGAINST suggestion and some PHP I solved it.

```
$SQLSet = mysql_query("
  SELECT DISTINCT i.*
  FROM items i
  JOIN wanted w ON MATCH(i.notes)
  AGAINST(\"".$SQLRowWanted['Notes']." +'".$SQLRowWanted['Name']."'\")
");
```

This is running inside a loop with $SQLRowWanted from an earlier call.
By encapsulating the Name column in '...' and adding a + before it, I get a higher match rate on the full name as well.

Comment: There is no combination of LIKE & IN in SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Comment: I didn't mean IN and LIKE as a pair, but as separate solutions I already tried. Is that unclear? Okay I will edit and again, thank you for your help  with my questions so far ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at using Full Text Search (FTS).  [MySQL has native FTS functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) using the `MATCH ... AGAINST` function, but it requires that a full text index exist on the column(s).  MySQL's Full Text index can only be applied to MyISAM tables, for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

```
SELECT i.id,
       i.notes
  FROM ITEMS i
  JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON MATCH(i.notes) AGAINST (c.notes IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Otherwise, you'll need to look at 3rd party FTS:

- Sphinx
- Solr (lucene based)

Comment: I changed both tables to MyISAM table engines and created a FULLTEXT index for the 'Notes' column in both tables. As long I put a string in the AGAINST parameter it works fine 'SELECT DISTINCT i.* FROM items i JOIN customers c ON MATCH(i.notes) AGAINST("bag fork")'. But if I use the column, as in your example 'SELECT DISTINCT i.* FROM items i JOIN customers c ON MATCH(i.notes) AGAINST(c.notes)', I get the error "Incorrect arguments to AGAINST, ErrorNr. 1210" I have seen other having the same problem and it seems like AGAINST() only takes a STRING CONSTANT.

Comment: @Max Kielland: Try adding the `IN BOOLEAN MODE` -- see my update.

Comment: Nope, your update didn't help. I have seen in some forums that it has to be a constant (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,173549,173736#msg-173736). Some points out that a "prepared statement" would do the trick. Anyway, you pointed me in the right direction and I have solved AGAINST constant issue with PHP. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your table is not normalised, which makes it harder. For each of "1: bag candle fork" you should have a seperate row:

```
notesID | noteText
1         bag
1         candle
1         fork
2         max
2         kielland
...
```

Then you can simply do

```
SELECT * FROM customers, items WHERE customers.noteText = items.noteText;
```

You may need to create seperate tables with just the two columns shown above, and join them back to your customers and items table to look up more data.

Comment: Did you mean seperate tables and not seperate databases

Comment: This column 'notes' works like a post-it, I need to keep it in the same way so I can show this as a "post-it" toolTip. If I do as you suggest I will lose the formatting.