# Anonymous TABLE or VARRAY type in Oracle

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, anonymous-types

In Oracle, I would sometimes like to create constructs such as these ones

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(STRINGS('a', 'b', 'c'))
SELECT * FROM TABLE(NUMBERS(1, 2, 3))
```

Obviously, I can declare my own types for the above. I can choose between `TABLE` and `VARRAY`. For example:

```
CREATE TYPE STRINGS AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
CREATE TYPE NUMBERS AS VARRAY(100) OF NUMBER(10);
```

In this particular case, another solution is to write things like

```
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' FROM DUAL
```

But I may have more complex examples where I will really need a `TABLE` / `VARRAY` type. So what if my SQL is running on an unknown system where I cannot create types because I may not have the necessary grants?

**So my question is:** Does Oracle know "anonymous" `TABLE` / `VARRAY` types that are available on any Oracle instance? Similar to Postgres / H2 / HSQLDB's simple `ARRAY` types?

**UPDATE**: I am mostly running this SQL from Java, if this is relevant. No need to explain PL/SQL to me, I'm really just looking for anonymous SQL array types (i.e. "anonymous" *standalone stored types*). If they don't exist at all, the answer is *NO*

Comment: Have you considered using PLSQL?

Comment: @Rene: "*My SQL is running on an unknown system where I cannot create types*", so I cannot use PL/SQL, as I may not be able to create the necessary types / functions... unless you mean anonymous PL/SQL blocks? How would you solve this generally, then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### SQL table and varray types

An interesting solution was given by user [APC here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785459/anonymous-table-or-varray-type-in-oracle#8786450). For future readers of this question, it may be interesting to see that this query provides what I'm really interested in:

```
select coll_type, elem_type_name, type_name, length, upper_bound
from all_coll_types
where owner = 'SYS'
and elem_type_name IN ('VARCHAR2', 'NUMBER')
order by coll_type, elem_type_name, type_name;
```

Resulting in (in Oracle 11g):

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------+------+-----------+
|COLL_TYPE    |ELEM_TYPE_NAME|TYPE_NAME             |LENGTH|UPPER_BOUND|
+-------------+--------------+----------------------+------+-----------+
|TABLE        |NUMBER        |KU$_OBJNUMSET         |{null}|     {null}|
|TABLE        |NUMBER        |KU$_XMLCOLSET_T       |{null}|     {null}|
|TABLE        |NUMBER        |ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT  |{null}|     {null}|
|TABLE        |VARCHAR2      |DBMS_AW$_COLUMNLIST_T |   100|     {null}|
|TABLE        |VARCHAR2      |DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL    |  1000|     {null}|
|TABLE        |VARCHAR2      |HSBLKNAMLST           |    30|     {null}|
|TABLE        |VARCHAR2      |KU$_VCNT              |  4000|     {null}|
|TABLE        |VARCHAR2      |ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT|  4000|     {null}|
|VARYING ARRAY|NUMBER        |AWRRPT_NUM_ARY        |{null}|         30|
|VARYING ARRAY|NUMBER        |JDM_NUM_VALS          |{null}|        999|
|VARYING ARRAY|NUMBER        |ODCIGRANULELIST       |{null}|      65535|
|VARYING ARRAY|NUMBER        |ODCINUMBERLIST        |{null}|      32767|
|VARYING ARRAY|NUMBER        |SQL_OBJECTS           |{null}|       2000|
|VARYING ARRAY|NUMBER        |TABLESPACE_LIST       |{null}|      64000|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |AQ$_JMS_NAMEARRAY     |   200|       1024|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |AQ$_MIDARRAY          |    32|       1024|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |AWRRPT_VCH_ARY        |    80|         30|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY | 32767| 2147483647|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |DBMS_XS_ROLELIST      |  1024|       4096|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |FLASHBACKTBLIST       |    30|        100|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |HSBLKVALARY           |  4000|        250|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |JDM_ATTR_NAMES        |    60|        999|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |JDM_STR_VALS          |  4000|        999|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |KU$_DROPCOLLIST       |  4000|       1000|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |KUPC$_LOBPIECES       |  4000|       4000|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |ODCIRIDLIST           |  5072|      32767|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |ODCIVARCHAR2LIST      |  4000|      32767|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |RE$NAME_ARRAY         |    30|       1024|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |RE$RULE_LIST          |    65|       1024|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |SQLPROF_ATTR          |   500|       2000|
|VARYING ARRAY|VARCHAR2      |TXNAME_ARRAY          |   256|        100|
+-------------+--------------+----------------------+------+-----------+
```

It looks as though `ORA_MINING_NUMBER_NT` and `ORA_MINING_VARCHAR2_NT` will be the best match for my needs.

#### PL/SQL indexed array types

If using Oracle 12c and PL/SQL, there's also the possibility to use any of the `DBMS_SQL` types, which can be unnested using the `TABLE(..)` constructor. There are:

- `DBMS_SQL.CLOB_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.BINARY_FLOAT_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.BINARY_DOUBLE_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.BLOB_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.BFILE_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.DATE_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.UROWID_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.TIME_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.TIME_WITH_TIME_ZONE_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.TIMESTAMP_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.TIMESTAMP_WITH_LTZ_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND_TABLE`
- `DBMS_SQL.INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH_TABLE`

Comment: Maybe you can use SYS.FI_NUMERICALS and SYS.FI_CATEGORICALS for the same purpose.

Answer (score 21):

Providing you're not scared of explicitly referencing the SYS schema there are a few.  Here are some I use quite often (well `odcivarchar2list` not so much, as it chews up a lot of memory: for strings I prefer `dbms_debug_vc2coll`).

```
SQL> desc sys.odcinumberlist
 sys.odcinumberlist VARRAY(32767) OF NUMBER

SQL> desc sys.odcivarchar2list
 sys.odcivarchar2list VARRAY(32767) OF VARCHAR2(4000)

SQL> desc sys.ODCIDATELIST
 sys.ODCIDATELIST VARRAY(32767) OF DATE

SQL> desc sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
 sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000)

SQL>
```

However, if those aren't sufficient for your needs run this query to find some more:

```
select type_name
       , owner
from all_types
where typecode = 'COLLECTION'
and owner != user
/
```

Of course, this result will vary from database to database.  For instance a lot of the colllections on my database are owned by XDB and not every system will have that installed.  The four I listed at the the top of this answer should be available on every database since 9iR2 (and perhaps early) although they are not always documented in earlier versions.

---

> "Note that ALL_COLL_TYPES seems to be an even better dictionary view
>   to find appropriate types"

That's a good point.  We can also filter on COLL_TYPE to winnow out the VARRAYs.  That view was introduced into 10g whereas ALL_TYPES was available on 9i.  As with most things Oracle, the later the version the more functionality it has.

Comment: That is a quite interesting approach. Not what I had in mind, but definitely clever! :-) Note that `ALL_COLL_TYPES` seems to be an even better dictionary view to find appropriate types (you can filter on `ELEM_TYPE_NAME = 'VARCHAR2'` for instance...

Comment: **accepted answer**: Short of true anonymous types, I guess this is as good as it gets. Thanks!

Comment: I have added a query and its results [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785459/anonymous-table-or-varray-type-in-oracle/8786893#8786893) to document what I get when querying for `ALL_COLL_TYPES`...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very general - basically you can use these (`VARARRAY` / `TABLE`) without an explicit `CREATE TYPE` in anonymous PL/SQL blocks like this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE genres IS VARRAY(4) OF book_genre.genre_name%TYPE;
    Fiction_genres genres;
    TYPE phone_no_tab IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR2(20) ;
    phone_nos phone_no_tab;
BEGIN
    fiction_genres := genres('MYSTERY','SUSPENSE', 'ROMANCE','HORROR');
    phone_nos := phone_no_tab();
    phone_nos.EXTEND(2);
    phone_nos(1) := '0117 942 2508';
END;
```

OR like this

```
declare

  TYPE auftrag_table_typ IS TABLE OF auftrag%ROWTYPE
          INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  auftrag_table auftrag_table_typ;

  v_index BINARY_INTEGER;

begin

  v_index := auftrag_table.first;

  while v_index is not NULL loop

    // do something with auftrag_table(v_index)

    v_index := auftrag_table.next (v_index);

  end loop;

end;
```

For Oracle reference see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm - according to this any such `VARARRAY` and/or `TABLE` needs to be `DECLARE`d or created via `CREATE TYPE`, so AFAIK there is no such thing as "anonymous `VARARRAY` / `TABLE`".

Comment: I can see how it can be done with PL/SQL. But when calling the statement from Java, is an anonymous PL/SQL block wrapper around the actual SQL statement really the best solution? Instead of a simple SQL statement, I'd then have to prepare a call and probably register a `REF CURSOR` parameter to return the results...?

Comment: @LukasEder your question is extremely general... and I don't know of any "best solution" in programming - it all depends on what you want to do... you asked whether these can be used without `CREATE TYPE` privilege - and that's what I answered... I don't see anything wrong with having to prepare a statement - I would even say that preparing a statement is in most cases recommended... please say what exactly you want to achieve...

Comment: The question is quite clear. I'm looking for anonymous array types. If it doesn't exist, then the answer is simply *NO*. You're making too many assumptions about a hypothetical problem I might have :)

Comment: PL/SQL `TABLE` and `VARRAY` types cannot be used in SQL anyway (except with constructs such as `BULK COLLECT INTO`). So this is also true for SQL types?

Comment: @LukasEder what do you mean by "SQL types" ?

Comment: According to your link they're better called *standalone stored types*, rather than *SQL types*. Please note, I'm asking this because the `COLLECT` operator creates a "temporary" type for similar purposes. Maybe there is a way to achieve what I want, using "anonymous" types

Comment: @LukasEder `COLLECT` basically does a `CREATE TYPE` in the schema of the caller - you can verify that by looking at `all_types`.