# Oracle's analogue for unnest array from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, unnest

I have table with subnetworks like

```
cidr | ip
```

And I want to select subnetworks by list of belonging ips. In postgres I can do it in this way:

```
select 
    ips.ip, net.uid, net.cidr 
from 
    TBL_SID_SUBNETWORK net, 
    (select unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) ip) ips 
where 
    cast (((2^net.cidr) - 1) as bigint)<<(32 - net.cidr) & ips.ip =  net.ipaddress
```

In postgres I can pass array and use it as a table.

```
select ips.ip from
(select unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) ip) ips

|ip|
 1
 2
 3
```

Is it possible to do something like that in Oracle? In one query? I don't want to create, populate and drop additional table, because I use DB indirectly, and transaction is managed by application configuration.

I know about Oracle's `TABLE(collection)` function which does merely the same what I want. But I can't pass collection into this query, 'cause I should declare and populate collection before, and in this way it's the same as creating temp table.

Comment: Is the problem with `TABLE` just that you don't want to define a collection?  If so, there are pre-defined, documented collections you can use.  For example: `select column_value ip from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oracle has pre-defined, documented collections you can use.  For example:

```
select column_value ip from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3));
```

There's no one place that contains a list of all documented collections.  [This page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI5012) of the *Database Data Cartridge Developer's Guide* lists some of the more popular ones, such as `ODCIVarchar2List`, `ODCINumberList`, and `ODCIDateList`.  Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786893/409172) by Lukas Eder uses a query to find system collections, although not all of them are documented.

It would be nice if Oracle just a few standard collections for everyone to use and gave them nice names.  It's safe to use `sys.odcinumberlist` but it looks like an ugly hack.

Comment: Do you have a link to any of the other documented collections?

Comment: @redbmk I updated my answer with some new information.

Comment: Thanks! Oracle's way sure make's postgreSQL's `unnest` seem a whole lot more pleasant