# List of values as table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, csv, oracle12c

I'm looking for a smarter way to have a list of values as a table in Oracle.

What I do nowadays is

```sql
select 'value1' as val from dual
 union
select 'value2' from dual
```

What I'm hoping for is some function/way/magic, that I'll do for example

```sql
select 'value1', 'value2' from dual -- + some additional magic
```

I'm looking for non-PL/SQL way which I think is overkill, but I'm not saying definite no to PL/SQL if that's the only option, but I can look here [Create an Oracle function that returns a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2829880/384674) for inspiration for PL/SQL. But extra table to have a list seems still easier to maintain than PL/SQL.

The motivation for not using `select distict` from transactional table is that I want to have a defined list of values, and with that approach, I can miss those I expect there but have no records in the table.

The expected number of elements in the list is several tens of records (like 30).

Comment: This seems like a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785459/anonymous-table-or-varray-type-in-oracle I tried to google it (before I asked) I found it only based on answers below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or yet another, similar:

```
SQL> select column_value
  2  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('Little', 'Foot', 'Scott', 'Tiger'))
  3  order by column_value;

COLUMN_VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Foot
Little
Scott
Tiger

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. PL/SQL I do not need to maintain is better than what I had in mind.

Comment: I had to pick a "winner", so I picked this one. [Here](https://developpaper.com/examples-of-anonymous-table-varray-types-in-sql-oracle/) the author says `odcivarchar2list is not good, because it chews a lot of memory` which is ok for my usage (short list of values).

Comment: In my case I asked about strings (varchar in Oracle DB), there is also `OdciNumberList` for numbers...

Comment: Yes, there is - but, as you said, you asked about strings. Those built-in types are sometimes handy (like in your case) as you don't have to create your own ones.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option:

```
select column_value 
from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'));
```

Starting Oracle 12.2, you don't need the `table` function:

```
select column_value 
from sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4');
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. PL/SQL I do not need to maintain is better than what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Oracle 12c you could use [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) for that:

```
select *
from json_table('["value1", "value2"]', '$[*]' 
                 columns val varchar(20) path '$');
```

Comment: This would be my preferred option if it's not a list of strings, but list of objects - `select *
from json_table('[ {foo: 1, bar: "value1"}, {foo: 2, bar: "value2"} ]', '$[*]' columns foo number path '$.foo', bar varchar2(20) path '$.bar');`

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't on 12c and can't use `json_table` (or even if you are/can but don't want to) you could use an XML sequence via `xmltable` instead:

```
select *
from xmltable('"value1", "value2", "value3"');

Result Sequence                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
value1
value2
value3
```

I'd probably use an ODCI collection by default, but might be interesting to compare how all of these options compare with large data volumes - with 30 values you might not be able to see much of a difference.

Comment: Thanks, with hundreds of records I'd use extra table, this might help someone in future... I'm on Oracle 12c (which I didn't mention too).

Comment: Well, this works on later versions too... I didn't phrase that very well *8-)

Answer (score 1):

Also, You can use the connect by query:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('VALUE1,VALUE2','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  2     connect by level <= regexp_count('VALUE1,VALUE2', '[^,]+');

REGEXP_SUBSTR('VALUE1,VALUE2','[^,]+',1,LEVEL)
----------------------------------------------------
VALUE1
VALUE2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked too, but at the moment I like the other two options (using PL/SQL) more as for me it's easier to read. I know I mentioned non-PL/SQL way in question, I hope you understand...