# sql query to get data having special characters from a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get data from this column having all kind of special charaters.

The special characters are as below:

```
&   *   ,   .   :   ;   `   ~   ¿   Ä   Å   Ç   É   Ñ   Ö   Ü   ß   à   á    
â   ä   å   ç   è   é   ê   ë   ì   í   î   ï   ñ   ò   ó   ô   ö   ù   ú    
û   ü   ÿ   ƒ   α
```

I am running the below query, but no result:

```
select A.Street  
from ADRC a
where A.Street like not LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9, ]%'
```

[image]

the above result is fetched from

```
select A.Street  
from ADRC a
```

when I am running the like clause i m not getting results.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support extended LIKE syntax or Regular Expression?

Comment: oracle. i can recognize the screen in the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIKE in an Oracle IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074201/using-like-in-an-oracle-in-clause)

Comment: `LIKE` does not support "regular expressions".

Comment: @ia_horse_with_no_name: Hi, given poster is attempting this already maybe they just didn't tag with relevant RDBMS?

Comment: I tried running all possible combinations of LIKE operator still I am stuck.I am not getting any results.Please help.    select A.Street  
from ADRC a
where A.Street  LIKE '[A-Za-z0-9, ]%';

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ that's not a duplicate at all. This question is about NOT LIKE statement with a regular expression support. It can't be expanded easily.

Comment: You use "like not LIKE". It's either "LIKE" or "NOT LIKE". Why don't you get a syntax error on this?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` to fetch any record that contains at least one "special" character:

```
select a.street
from adrc a
where REGEXP_LIKE (a.street, '[^A-Za-z0-9, ]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0aee/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**: Some test data with 1 character per row:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( a ) AS
SELECT SUBSTR( value, LEVEL, 1 )
FROM   (
  SELECT '&*,.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒα'
         || 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
         || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
         || '0123456789' AS value
  FROM   DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( value );
```

**Query 1**:

Naively, if you want to just match specific characters then you can just enumerate all the characters you want to match in a regular expression:

```
'[&*,.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒα]'
```

For example - this lists all the matched characters (aggregated into a single row for compactness):

```
SELECT LISTAGG( a, '' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS matches
FROM   table1
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( a, '[&*,.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒα]' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0aee/3/0)**:

```
|                                     MATCHES |
|---------------------------------------------|
| &*,.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒα |
```

**Query 2**:

If you know the characters you do not want to match then you can negate the pattern `[^characters to not match]` to find out whether there are any other characters:

For example:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( a, '' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS matches
FROM   table1
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( a, '[^a-z0-9, ]', 'i' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0aee/3/1)**:

```
|                                    MATCHES |
|--------------------------------------------|
| &*.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒα |
```

**Query 3**:

If you do not have a simple expression you can negate but, instead, want to match characters that are equivalent to base letters then you can use `[=a=]` to match `a`, `à`, `á`, `â`, `ä` or `å` and would give a regular expression like:

```
[[:punct:][=a=][=c=][=e=][=i=][=n=][=o=][=u=][=y=]αßƒ]
```

For example:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( a, '' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS matches
FROM   table1
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( a, '[[:punct:][=a=][=c=][=e=][=i=][=n=][=o=][=u=][=y=]αßƒ]', 'i' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0aee/3/2)**:

```
|                                                     MATCHES |
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| &*,.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒαaceinouyACEINOUY |
```

**Query 4**:

But that also matches the base characters, so we could negate the previous match and use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to strip out the non-matching characters and then test for the existence of a non-base character:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( a, '' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS matches
FROM   table1
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           a,
           '[^[:punct:][=a=][=c=][=e=][=i=][=n=][=o=][=u=][=y=]αßƒ]'
         ),
         '[^a-z]',
         'i'
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0aee/3/3)**:

```
|                                     MATCHES |
|---------------------------------------------|
| &*,.:;`~¿ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüÿƒα |
```