# EF Core Linq Query to Select Rows That Match From a List of Possibilities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ef-core-2.2

Assume a `DbSet<Thing> things`; and `Thing` has a `Name` property.

If I want to retrieve a list of things that match a list of names, it's pretty straightforward:

```cs
var names = new List<string>{"John", "Jacob", "Jinkelheimer", "Smith"};

return things.Where(t => names.Contains(t.name));
```

However, what if I want to match a list of *partial* name possibilities?

```cs
var nameBits = (new List<string>{"ohn", "mit"}).ToLower();

// this doesn't seem good / right / efficient
things.Where(t => nameBits
   .Select(bit => EF.Functions.Like(t.Name, $"%{bit}%")
   .Any(m => m)
);

// I could also go with:

things.Where(t => nameBits
     .Select(bit => t.Name.Contains(bit)).Any(m => m)
);
```

... but I don't know how efficient any of those will be.
How would I write the linq query that would efficiently match "John", "Johnathan", "Smith", "Smitty", etc using `ohn` and `mit`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033007

Comment: Sadly, SqlFunctions.PatIndex() will not work for my use case - I'm targeting an Oracle database.  :-(

Comment: Then your best bet is probably to write a raw SQL query.  I'll write an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about Entity Framework is that you can always drop to raw SQL when things aren't working out on the C# front.

```
var names = context.Names
    .FromSqlRaw("select Name from Names where name like %{0}%", name)
    .ToList();
```

[Writing Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: How do I use SQL to say "`where name like %a% or %b% or %c%`" - basically `like` "any item in this array"?

Comment: Is the list of names small enough where you can just bring the entire list into memory and use ordinary Linq on it?

Comment: I think we're looking at a Full Text Search.

Comment: I don't know if I can get that column indexed or not - do you think something like this might work? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230612/127888

Comment: It's worth a try.