# How to filter with multiple conditions in like: Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-like, multiple-conditions

I want to optimise the following SQL request (without creating another table):

```
Select * from table
where var1 like 'file_X_2022_1_001%' 
   or var1 like 'file_X_2022_1_004%' 
   or var1 like 'file_X_2022_1_006%'
   or var1 like 'file_X_2022_8_002%'
   or var1 like 'file_X_2022_8_0015%' 
   .
   .
   .
   or ... or var1 like 'file_X_2022_10_1000%';
```

I want something like `in()` where I can regroup all values in one parentheses :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the rule here for the file naming convention?  You haven't shown us all your data to be matched.

Comment: Apparently you're looking for dynamic SQL...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using LIKE in an Oracle IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074201/using-like-in-an-oracle-in-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your filtering conditions in the `WHERE` clause to one only with [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm).

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (var1, 'file_X_2022_[0-9]{1,2}_[0-9]?[0-9]{3}')
```

Pattern should be fine-tuned to exclude the values you don't allow. Values pointed in the post by you, get all caught by this regex.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XVBABGQe).