# Oracle: merging two different queries into one, LIKE & IN

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I need to implement a search query, where we have multiple filters(values) for a single column in database(oracle). But these multiple filters(values) are `LIKE` query parameters. I am not sure that whether I am visioning correct result using the approach in mind.

I want something that should work like:

```
departmentname IN ( LIKE '%Medi%', LIKE '%Ciga%')
```

I know it will not work, just I want to show the vision I am having.

Though we all know that its simple using `foreach` and manually adding `'OR'` between queries like:

```
WHERE DEPARTMENTNAME LIKE '%Medi%' OR '%Ciga%' OR '%Tobacc%'
```

But is there any way to implement it using IN() AND LIKE simultaneously?

Other suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: if it were possible to use in (like '', like ''), as you mention, I don't see how superior it would be to the OR version...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Comment: Just thought it was worth mentioning that using the wildcard operator at the start of a string can make these queries pretty slow as it will need to look at all the rows and even an index won't really help. (to my knowledge...)

Comment: Ben your link was very helpful..yap I was looking for same thing... but as everyone is mentioning that query will ate resources, and results in slow process.. I am planning to go with simple one `where departmentName like '%Medi%'
   or departmentName like '%Ciga%'
   or departmentName like '%Tabacc%';`
 at-last as I have no option left...

Answer (score 2):

As was already commented, it is better and simpler to just concatenate several conditions:

```
where departmentName like '%Medi%'
   or departmentName like '%Ciga%'
   or departmentName like '%Tabacc%';
```

Another way is to insert those values '%Medi%', '%Ciga%' and '%Tabacc%' into a conditionTable,  and then run this query:

```
select department.*
  from department
 cross join conditionTable
 where department.departmentName like conditionTable.value;
```

I am assuming here that your table is `department` and that the conditionTable has a column `value`. If you implement this solution, you should care about concurrency, and filter conditionTable by something like

```
select department.*
  from department
 inner join conditionTable on conditionTable.session = yourSessionId
 where department.departmentName like conditionTable.value;
```

Finally, a third solution that might be handy, if you dont want to use a conditionTable, is to generate a string `select <cond1> as value from dual union select <cond2> from dual...` and placed into a dynamic query as

```
select department.*
  from department
 cross join
   (select '%Medi%' as value from dual
     union
    select '%Ciga%' from dual
     union
    select '%Tabacc%' from dual) conditionTable
 where department.departmentName like conditionTable.value;
```

Comment: Thanks for such response jose... but I have to go either with `where departmentName like '%Medi%'
   or departmentName like '%Ciga%'
   or departmentName like '%Tabacc%';
` OR REGEXP_LIKE which seems to leech CPU :) ;P so I may drop the idea of using it.