# SQL Server IN statement with wildcard

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a combination of “LIKE” and “IN” in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

The first where clause below runs fine for me but it does not pick up contacts that might have 45211-1234 or 45213-4321

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE zipcode IN ('45211','45213')
```

I thought I could change the where clause to the below to fix, but it fails.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE zipcode IN ('45211%','45213%')
```

How might I change this so it brings back anything that has proper zip + dash + any zip4? For example, `45211-1234` or `45213-4321`.

Note I have whole bunch of zipcodes to enter, not just these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE Left(zipcode,5) IN ('45211','45213')
```

Comment: Works great and simple for me to understand. Thanks!