# Separate/Organize string values in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle10g

I Have requirement in Oracle 10g:
I need to select using an `in` clause.

The problem is the string which I want to use in the database is comma separated values product codes like `4435D,4436E,5656F, 5670L` in a single column.

What I want is something like `'4435D','4436E','5656F', '5670L'` which I can use as

```
Select * from sub_products 
where product_code in ('4435D','4436E','5656F', '5670L');
```

How do we achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hierarchical query to separate the values in the string.

```
with str as (
  select '4435D,4436E,5656F,5670L' s from dual)
select regexp_substr(s,'[^,]+',1,level) from str
connect by regexp_substr(s,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null;
```

output:

```
4435D
4436E
5656F
5670L
```

You can use this as subquery in your query. Sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13408)

Answer (score 0):

How about using like?

```
Select * from sub_products 
where product_code like '%4435D%' or product_code like '%5656F%' or product_code like '%5670L%';
```

Comment: Nope I do know what data would be there I just hard coded for your reference the column could have 1 value or 4 values comma separated . First I have to get them in a proper string format to use it in an IN clause right ? How do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CONTAINS keyword (check this : [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql))

```
WHERE CONTAINS(product_code,'4435D OR 4436E OR 5656F OR 5670L',1)>0
```