# Using LIKE "%this%" or "%that%"

Tags: sql, select

So I know that you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
    (column1 LIKE "%this%" OR column1 LIKE "%that%")
```

But is there a quicker way to do this?

Note that my columns are the same. Do I really have to enter `column1 LIKE` for each condition?

Comment: If you want to filter on it - yes.

Comment: Each set (Column like '%this%') is a filter condition.  Every time you want to add a filter condition - you need to specify the column to filter on and the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do, for a wildcard search. If however you dropped the wildcard and searched on just `this` and `that`, then you could use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE column1 IN ('this', 'that')
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008+ or Oracle, you can make use of full text search, doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE CONTAINS(column1, '*this*', '*that*')
```

Comment: I do need the wildcard. What is the purpose of the `*` in the CONTAINS example?

Comment: @Toiletduck `*` is the wild card character (`%` replacement) inside a `CONTAINS` full text search.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wha environment you are using, but it might be worth checking out:

[Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Comment: Try WHERE CONTAINS(column1 , '"%this%*" OR "%that%*" OR "%yourmom%*"')

Comment: What is the purpose of the Asterisk after the expression?

Comment: Like Mtty said, it's a wildcard