# How to/Possible to Generate String of Table Based Row Values for CONTAINS Search String?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, cursor, contains

So ideally I'd like to keep this within a query, but if it's not possible, I suppose a package could work as I have no webapp level to work with.

What I'd like to do is this, for an Oracle DB, create/run a query in the `where` clause such that for each row in a table with one attribute where all rows have substrings with wildcards are stored it adds on to the search string for `contains`. Since to my knowledge, you can't really do loops within queries, one would need a cursor, but I've never used cursors. Here is a more visual representation of what I'm trying to do (abet with loop logic):

**Table1**
 
Attribute: firstname

> John
>  Joe
>  Jane
>  Josephine

**Table2** 
 
Attribute: substrings

> %se%
>  %h%i%

Where by constraint there is guaranteed to always be at least one row

**Pseudo Query**

```
SELECT 
  table1.firstname
FROM
  table1
WHERE CONTAINS(table1.firstname, '"table2.row1"
  IF(count(table2.substrings) > 1)
    FOR table2.row = 2 TO count(table2.substrings)
      (
      + " OR row.substrings"
      )
 ', 1) > 0
```

(`CONTAINS` syntax based on [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what do you want to get, but I think these simple examples might help.

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where exists(
    select 1 from table2 t2
    where t1.firstname like t2.attribute
);


select t1.*,
       ( select listagg( ''''||t2.attribute||'''', ' OR ' ) WITHIN GROUP (order by t2.attribute )
         from table2 t2
         where t1.firstname like t2.attribute
       ) CONTAINS_argument
from table1 t1
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b99c0/4) of these queries.

Comment: First query is what I needed and after some fiddling got it to work in my environment. I tried the second one out of curiosity because I've never hear of listagg before and got a FROM not where expected error on the second line, but it's not that big of a deal considering it's #1 that I needed. DB was running Oracle 9, so I suspect it's a legacy syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some variants (according to my understanding of the question), based on usage of [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) and [multiset casts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions016.htm):

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fdd1/15)

All strings with matched patterns:

```
select
  t1.firstname,
  cast( multiset(
    select t2.attribute
    from table2 t2 
    where t1.firstname like t2.attribute
  ) as sys.ODCIVarchar2List)              pattern_list
from 
  table1 t1
;
```

All patterns with strings matched pattern:

```
select 
  t2.attribute,
  cast( multiset(
    select t1.firstname
    from table1 t1 
    where t1.firstname like t2.attribute
  ) as sys.ODCIVarchar2List)               word_list
from
  table2 t2
;
```

Construct patterns collection on the fly:

```
with table2 as (
  select '%se%' Attribute from dual union
  select '%h%i%' from dual   
)
select
  t1.firstname,
  cast( multiset(
    select t2.attribute
    from table2 t2 
    where t1.firstname like t2.attribute
  ) as sys.ODCIVarchar2List)               pattern_list
from 
  table1 t1;
```

Filter only matched:

```
select 
  firstname, 
  (select count(1) from table(pattern_list)) cnt,
  pattern_list
from (
  select
    t1.firstname,
    cast( multiset(
      select t2.attribute
      from table2 t2 
      where t1.firstname like t2.attribute
    ) as sys.ODCIVarchar2List)             pattern_list
  from 
    table1 t1
)
where (select count(1) from table(pattern_list)) > 0;
```

And so on.