# Spring Data: can it find by two values of the same field without writing the implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am doing a Spring web app and I use Spring Data.

I am able to use Spring Data to find objects by a single value of a field. For example:

```
some_object_repository.findByFirstName("John")
```

Is there any way I can provide two first names (e.g., "John", "David") similar to the following in concept:

```
some_object_repository.findByFirstName({"John", "David"})
```

without me writing a custom implementation?

Regards and thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this with In at the end

> findByAgeIn(Collection ages) … where x.age in ?1

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods

Section 2.3.2 Query creation

In your case it will be

> findByFirstNameIn(Collection names)

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer. It is helpful! Just one more question: is it possible to do a single value in one field, and two or more values (IN) in another field at the same time?

Comment: As far as I remember, there should be no problems with that. It will look like something like this: findByEmailAddressAndLastnameIn(String email, Collection<String> lastNames)

Comment: Is there a way to do %LIKE% search with an IN clause?

Comment: @Rahulkalivaradarajalu no! there is no chance to use `like` within `in` conditions. You can use completely different approach by using `containing` for more info visit the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016918/3881354 and the above-mentioned Spring Data JPA's doc.