# Searching for multiple words in spring data repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a PagingAndSortingRepository:

```
public interface BrowserLinkPagination extends PagingAndSortingRepository<BrowserLink, Long> {
    List<BrowserLink> findByUserAndUriLike(User user, String uri, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Now what I want to do is to search for multiple words in the `uri` column. `Like` comes pretty close, but it is order dependent on how the words occur in the string.
**EDIT** for clarification: Order dependences is exactly what I not want. I want the search strings to be independent of order, so `LIKE` is not what I am looking for.

I guess this is pretty common to find, having several search terms to look for in a string, I know I could implement it by providing the SQL to execute, but I am curiuous if there is a way to express that in terms of spring data? am

I am using postgresql for production and h2 for development / tests.

Comment: I think don't think it solves your issue, but you may take a look at "IN":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902954/spring-data-can-it-find-by-two-values-of-the-same-field-without-writing-the-imp

Comment: As far as I can tell `IN`looks for exact matches like ids or similar things. I want more of a substring search.

Comment: If the order is important what is holding you back from using `LIKE` with something like `'%first%second%third%'`? Performance will be crappy but you should be able to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I updated the post that order dependence is what I not want.

Comment: Then you should be looking at document store such as Elasticsearch or Mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

After reading more about the topic it is kind of obvious I need some kind of fulltext search.
I will start using the one provided by postgresql. I found a short working example: http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use `In` in method name. In Your case it could look like that:

```
public interface BrowserLinkPagination extends PagingAndSortingRepository<BrowserLink, Long> {
    List<BrowserLink> findByUserAndUriIn(User user, List<String> uri, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When You are using the standard API created by Spring, the usage from the browser URI is pretty simple - just type in the address:

```
/your_api/browserlink/search/findByUserAndUriIn?user=xxx&uri=uri1,uri2,uri3
```