# using 'LIKE IN' in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-like

So it's just a simple question I have this query. It's not working so I just thought I'd make sure that this isn't possible.

```
SELECT * FROM warehouse WHERE sku LIKE IN ($clean) AND style= :style9 ORDER BY sku ASC
```

Comment: What is `$clean`? What is the expected outcome? `LIKE` and `IN` both exist, but `LIKE IN` doesn't, and I can't think of any artifact that would behave the way I think you want (if `$clean` were a list of string patterns).

Comment: is $clean a comma separated list?

Comment: $clean is simply a set of strings separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognize `LIKE IN` as a thing.

You might try `sku LIKE '%' + ($clean) + '%'`

Or, if you're looking for it the other way around: `($clean) LIKE '%' + sku + '%'`

[Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql) Here is a discussion of using Contains, if you would like to try using that.

Answer (score 1):

```
There is no combination of LIKE & IN in SQL,so you have to use sql like

SELECT * FROM warehouse WHERE sku LIKE '%$clean%' AND style= :style9 ORDER BY sku ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Like and In both are different thing, you can easily understand from the below snippet of code, hopefully this will help you to remove your confusion :)

```
select 
    *
from
    emp
where
    name like @param +'%'

Select
   *
from
   emp where name in ('abc', 'xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your `$clean` value looks like (or your `sku` values or expected results) I can only guess, but [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html), also known as `RLIKE`, might be useful here.

Say you're looking for SKU's like 'AB%', 'XY%', and 'FG%'. You can do that with `RLIKE` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM warehouse WHERE sku RLIKE '^(AB|XY|FG)' AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEXP to achieve what your trying to achieve, so you query will look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM warehouse 
WHERE sku REGEXP REPLACE($clean,',','|') AND style= :style9 
ORDER BY sku ASC
```

Going on the assumption that $clean is comma delimited list of values.