# a combination between a like and in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute the following:

```
Where Column_1 in ( (like '[BRCD]%'), 'J68', 'ESB')
```

So what I was trying to achieve was all values will be shown with the following letters: `B`,`R`,`C` or `D` (Please note the characters following behind those letters will be numbers) and then I wanted it to search for specific values as well `J68` and `ESB` but **SQL** doesn't like this and I can't seem to get it to display the set of data that I would like.

Comment: separate LIKE with RegEx and OR in

Comment: to elaborate on @techspider where Column_1 in('J68','ESB') or Column_1 LIKE  '[BRCD]%'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix like that

```
Where Column_1 in ('J68', 'ESB')
   or Column_1 like '[BRCD]%'
```

If you need more like then you need more or

scsimimon had this as a comment but it is an answer

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Thank you