# Combining "in" and "like" in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables, `plan` and `account`, and I also have two classes, `Plan` and `Account`, that represent these tables.

`Account` has fields, `id`, `plan_id`, `vdn` and `type`. `Plan` has fields, `id` and a few other irrelevant ones. It's structured so that a plan can be assigned to multiple accounts.

My `Plan` class has a field called `accounts`, which is mapped like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "plan", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@OrderBy(value = "type")
@LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Account> accounts;
```

So a plan has a list of all the accounts it's associated with. What I'm trying to do is filter the list of plans using `vdns` that belong to its corresponding accounts.

For example, if one plan belongs to an account with `vdn` "abc" and another plan belongs to an account with `vdn` "123", the user can search by the string "ab" and "12" to find them both.

Here is what I have so far:

```
criteria.createCriteria("accounts").add(Restrictions.in("vdn", new String[] { "abc", "123" }));
```

This code works, but it only matches the strings exactly. If a user enters "abc" then it will find that plan. If a user enters "ab" it will not find the plan.

So far, I've also tried something like:

```
criteria.createCriteria("accounts").add(Restrictions.in("vdn", new String[] { "%ab%", "%12%" }));
```

but that hasn't worked.

Is there a way to use the "like" restriction along with the "in" restriction?

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql