# SQL LIKE words comma separated?

Tags: sql

```
$string = "San Martin, Mendoza, Argentina"
```

How do I match Mendoza in this sting with like statement?

```
'San Martin,%'
```

But not sure how for Mendoza?

Comment: `LIKE '%Mendoza%'` (But never, ever store data as comma separated items.)

Comment: Thanks but I need to match the entire or individual work with the comma at the end!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Comment: But you have no comma after Argentina... How do you know if an item is first, middle or last? As I said, comma separated items are a mess - will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: This is my query: $sql[] = 'address LIKE \'% '.$word.',%\' OR \''.$word.',%\' OR \'% '.$word.' %\' OR `address` LIKE \'% '.$word.'\' OR `address` LIKE \''.$word.' %\' OR `address` = \''.$word.'\' ';

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select rows with `Mendoza` in `$string` you can do

```
LIKE '%Mendoza%';
```

If you also want to ignore lower/uppercase, you can do

```
LOWER( string ) LIKE  '%mendoza%'
```

`%` is a SQL wildcard, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: I think this is what I want: '% murcia,%

Comment: The important parts are the `%` wildcards though.

Comment: What do you think about my query: $sql[] = 'address LIKE \'% '.$word.',%\' OR \''.$word.',%\' OR \'% '.$word.' %\' OR `address` LIKE \'% '.$word.'\' OR `address` LIKE \''.$word.' %\' OR `address` = \''.$word.'\' ';

Comment: Hm, looks like you want to a bit more complex logic on the string. Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x#2685 to find out how to split the string and work with the individual items.