# NOT LIKE IN statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to print names that do not start and end with vowel. I tried it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM people WHERE
lower(name) NOT LIKE IN ('a','e','i','o','u')%('a','e','i','o','u');
```

I got error.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try avoid using `REGEXP` from performance reasons in case of large data sets.

In such case is `TRANSLATE` your friend.

1) translate all vowels to one representative

2) perform normal LIKE predicate with the selected vowel

```
select txt from tab1
where translate(lower(txt),'aeiou','aaaaa') not like 'a%a';
```

**REGEXP**s are mighty, but should not be used on non-trivial data sets in case that they could be avoided. (My 8M rows test data gives 7 seconds elapsed using `TRANSLATE` vs. 2+ minutes with `REGEXP`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`regexp_like`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) with match parameter `i` for case insensitive matching:

```
select distinct name from people
where not regexp_like(name, '^[aeiou]($|.*[aeiou]$)', 'i');
```

Pattern details:

- `^[aeiou]` - starts with a vowel
- `($|.*[aeiou]$)` - either there is only one character (matched in the first step) or ends with a vowel.