# MySQL match input using wildcards stored in database

Tags: mysql, wildcard

I have stored a wildcard expression in MySQL table, and given a string, I want to see which records' expression will match to that of the string. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to provide some more information, such as a create table, sample data, and what you've tried so far. We can't help without knowing what you have

Comment: this link can help you similar to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql