# PHP SQL Match like value from array

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sql-like, sql-in

So I am using PHP and SQL (PDO) to write a query that would take values from an array of check box's (names[]) so for instance someone could submit the values "Bob", "John" and "Bill" and I want to match those with a column in the database.

Problem: Database is an import from Excel spreadsheet used for years and there is no set format for the column I match with, some examples of values stored the database could look like any of the following:

```
"Bill & Bob"
Bill
John and Bill
"Bill"
John, Bill, and Bob
John will perform the task
```

As you can see I need to use `Like %value%` to match values because The post request will send just Bill, John and Bob. My problem is how do I do it with the array passed because it could be just John or it could be 2 or all 3, but you can't use something like `WHERE column LIKE in(array)` correct? Would my best bet be to run the query once for each name and append the results to a single array? I know I could make some sort of dynamic statement that is something like:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%Bob%' OR
 column LIKE '%John%' OR
 column LIKE '%Bill%';
```

My problem doing it that way is that the above method is susceptible to SQL injection if the input isn't satisfied correct? Even if I use a bindValue() and make each one a bindable variable then I have to figure out how many binds there are and I feel like if I have to add names in the future it would be more difficult than it should be. Is the best way to do it what I said above about one query executed multiple times for, once for each name and then append the results together?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Driver is PDO, Engine is MSSQL

Comment: Side note: You should normalize your database. What you have now presents quite a few problems.

Comment: Database engine is MSSQL I mean to put that and that I was using PDO as the driver. I will edit post.

Comment: Can the user enter anything they want? Or are the checkboxes defined names?

Comment: [related, if not a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Comment: So the form that users submit includes currently 9 names (which can and probably will change in the future), 5 different departments, the 12 months and then 2 text boxes that match the task name and task descriptions. The checkboxes themselves are defined names and values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
//Prepare an array with names
$names = [
  ':name_1' => '%Bob%',
  ':name_2' => '%Bill%',
];
//build the where 
$whereQuery = '';
foreach($names as $bind => $value) {
  if(empty($whereQuery)) $whereQuery .= ' OR ';
  $whereQuery .= ' column LIKE '.$bind;
}
//here is missing the code with SQL and pdo preparing query
//after preparing query just execute with $names
$sth->execute($names);
```

**Be careful** this example provide only code helping you to figure out the solution.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely normalize your database.

But just quick approach and since php was mentioned you can generate query like

```
$names = ['John','Bob','Bill'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_weird_table WHERE ';
$first = true;
foreach ($names as $name) {
    if ($first) {
        $query .= '`column` LIKE "%'.$name.'%" ';
        $first  = false;
    } else {
         $query .= 'OR `column` LIKE "%'.$name'.'%" ';
    }
}
```