# How can query be optimized?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, sql-in

I have a simple select query on a table, but with different values in LIKE operator. Query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM BatchServices.dbo.TaskLog
WHERE EntryTime BETWEEN '20190407' AND '20190408' AND
      TaskGroup LIKE '%CSR%' AND
      (LogText LIKE '%error%' OR LogText LIKE '%fail%')
```

This above query is fine and returning me the expected results but I don't want to have multiple LIKE in a query, so I have already tried something like

```
SELECT *
from BatchServices.dbo.TaskLog
WHERE taskgroup = 'csr' AND
      LogText IN ( '%error%','%fail%') AND 
      EntryTime>'2019-04-07'
ORDER BY EntryTime ASC
```

This query is not giving me any results.
I am expecting a query which looks smarter than the one I have which returns result. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Comment: You need to use multiple `LIKE` in SQL Server.  Or a full-text index.

Comment: SQL Server supports full text searching which can search in multiple columns at once

Comment: "I don't want to have multiple ..." is not a reason for changing a working query.

Comment: @SMor I know that's not the reason but I just want to know is there any way to reduce the lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `like operator` with `OR` condition

```
SELECT * from BatchServices.dbo.TaskLog WHERE taskgroup ='csr' AND 
(LogText like '%error%' or LogText like '%fail%')
AND EntryTime>'2019-04-07' 
ORDER BY EntryTime ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE operators are not the problem. It's the leading wild cards. Unless you cant get rid of those, your optimization options are going to be limited to making sure you have a covering index on EntryTime... That and replacing the "*" with the specific columns you need.