# JPA separately to search for multiple words in one column

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Is there a way to search multiple words separately in a column - something like:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE LOWER(a.text) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',:word1,'%')) AND LOWER(a.text) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',:word2,'%'))")
```

But to work for multiple words `ArrayList<String> words`.

Comment: There is nothing like that in JPA QL. Or in standart SQL, for that matter. You will either have to develop a Criteria query or use a native query if your database supports something like CONTAINS (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql ) but that is - in my understanding - no standart.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this by building a dynamic query using Criteria API.

Your specification could look like:

```
Specification<Article> forWords(Collection<String> words) {
    if(words == null || words.isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("List of words cannot be empty.");

    return (root, query, builder) -> words.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .map(word -> "%" + word + "%")
            .map(word -> builder.like(builder.lower(root.get("text")), word))
            .reduce(builder::or)
            .get();

}
```

and then it can be executed on `JpaSpecificationExecutor<Article>`-enabled repository:

```
List<String> words = ...; //your logic to get words
List<Article> matches = articleRepository.findAll(forWords(words));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to it in without Criteria API you also can use `REGEXP`. You have to join your list before you pass it to the Repository like in Kotlin:

```
val joinedWords = words.joinToString(separator = "|")
```

now you can use it in the query like this.

```
SELECT a 
FROM Article a 
WHERE a.text REGEXP :joinedWords
```