# Is there a LIKE operator for a dynamic list or set of multiple strings on MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-like

Suppose I have a result set of only one column containing `substrings`:

Table1:

```
substrings
-----------
substringa
substringb
substringc
substringd
substringe
etc.
-----------
```

And I have a second result set from another query:

Table2:

```
id      | comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001    | A text containing substringa
0002    | A text containing substringd
0003    | A text containing none of the substrings from Table1
0004    | Another text containing substringa
0005    | A text containing substringb
...     | etc.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to return a third table, Table3, containing the rows in Table2 where the comment contains any of the `substrings` existing in Table1, including another column with the existing `substrings` itself, i.e.:

Table3:

```
id      | comment                                | substrings
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0001    | A text containing substringa           | substringa
0002    | A text containing substringd           | substringd
0004    | Another text containing substringa     | substringa
0005    | A text containing substringb           | substringb
...     | etc.                                   | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It can be assumed that all the comments in Table2 contains exactly zero or one of the substrings in Table1.
I tried looking for a solution using a combination of `charindex`, `substring`, `exists` or `like` operators but failed to come up with any solution, and MS SQL Server has no suitable `regexp` operator that I know of. Is there something similar to a `like` operator to check for multiple strings on MS SQL Server, or are there better methods to do this? The size of `substrings` in Table1 is in the order 10^2-10^3 and is dynamically changing, so I cannot hardcode as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3016918/5881159).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use use `CHARINDEX()` to check if a string contains another string:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.substring
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON CHARINDEX(t1.substring, t2.comment) > 0
```

If you want to see also comments that do not have a matched substring, you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

`LIKE` would get the job done as well:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.substring
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.comment LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.substring, '%')
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, somehow `CONCAT` or `'%' + t1.substring + '%'` did not work and I instead get duplicates of rows which fulfill the criteria. However `CHARINDEX` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this query:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.substring
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.comment LIKE '%' + t1.substring + '%'
```