# Is there an SQL operator in Amazon Redshift which is working as LIKE and IN operator together?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have to take many values from a table, which are written differently.
Usually, I use ILIKE operator, but in my case, I think that it will take more time.
Unfortunately, Redshift doesn't support LIKE IN operator. 
I will be very happy if somebody can give me a hint on solving this.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you want matched.

Comment: [Is there a combination of “LIKE” and “IN” in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql/52264937)

Answer (score 3):

[Redshift supports regular expressions.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html)  So, if you wanted to look for "car", "train", or "boat" in a string, you can use:

```
where col ~ 'car|train|boat'
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
where col like '%car%' or
      col like '%train%' or
      col like '%boat%'
```