# SQL : IN operator vs multiple ORs

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a behaviour I would like to understand for good.

Query #1:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE message like '%TEXT1%'
```

Output : `504`

Query #2

```
SELECT count(distinct id) FROM table WHERE message like '%TEXT2%'
```

Output : `87`

Query #3

```
SELECT count(distinct id) FROM table WHERE message in ('%TEXT1%','%TEXT2%' )
```

Output : `0`

I want to understand why am I getting zero in the third query. Based on [this](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/), the `( , )` is equivalent to a multiple `OR`. Isn't this `OR` inclusive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the `( , )` is equivalent to a multiple `OR`. Isn't this `OR` inclusive ?

Sure, it's inclusive. But it's still an **equality** comparison, with no wildcard matching. It's like writing

```
WHERE (message = '%TEXT1%' or message = '%TEXT2%')
```

rather than

```
WHERE (message LIKE '%TEXT1%' or message LIKE '%TEXT2%')
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL we could also use [Is there a combination of “LIKE” and “IN” in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264937/5070879) - `WHERE message LIKE ANY '{"%TEXT1%", "%TEXT2%"'}`

Answer (score 2):

`IN` does not take wildcards.  They are specific to `LIKE`.

So, you need to use:

```
WHERE message like '%TEXT1%'  OR message like '%TEST2%'
```

Or, you can use regular expressions:

```
WHERE message ~ 'TEXT1|TEXT2'
```

Comment: Okay, can you please indicate me the documentation that specifies this ?

Comment: @occulti: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN

Answer (score 2):

`IN` checks if the value on its left-hand side is *equal* to any of the values in the list. It does not support pattern matching.

This behavior is standard ANSI SQL, and is also described in [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR):

> `expression IN (value [, ...])`
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions. The result is “true” if the left-hand expression's result is equal to any of the right-hand expressions. This is a shorthand notation for:
>
> `expression = value1 OR expression = value2 OR ...`

So if you want to match against several possible patterns, you need `OR`:

```
where message like '%TEXT1%' or message like '%TEST2%'
```

Comment: Okay, can you please indicate me the documentation that specifies this ?

Comment: @occulti: this is SQL standard. I added a link to Postgres documentation in my answer.