# Combining IN and LIKE Functionality

Tags: sql-server

I want to filter all entry where Name is like 'Aay%' , 'Ara%', 'Kim%', .....

For `IN`, I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE 
WHERE NAME IN @List_OF_NAME
```

For `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE NAME LIKE 'Aay%'
```

Is there anyway to combine the two approach. so, that I get all the entry where name is like `'Aay%' , 'Ara%', 'Kim%'.....`? Any leads to get this functionality?

EDIT: I tried the approach mentioned here: [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

But, I get this error:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'Name' because it is not full-text indexed

Answer (score 0):

There is no short-circuit expression for `LIKE`, as `IN` for equality. You do need to repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE NAME LIKE 'Aay%' OR NAME LIKE 'Ara%' OR NAME LIKE 'Kim%'
```

If you have a large list of values, you might want to put them in a derived table, and use `EXISTS`, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (VALUES ('Aay%'), ('Ara%'), ('Kim%')) x(NAME)
    WHERE t.NAME LIKE x.NAME
)
```

Expanding that logic, you could very well use a table variable, or a temporary table instead of `VALUES()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in the three first letters for all the cases, you could take the left part and use the IN clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE LEFT(NAME, 3) IN ('Aay', 'Ara', 'Kim')
```