# How to match an array of substrings to db

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table like this:

| name | favorite_food |
| --- | --- |
| Mario | Burritos |
| Sam | Sushi |
| Cameron | Pizza |
| Samantha | Burgers |
| Victor | Salad |

Now let's say I want to search this table with an array of names to match people I'm looking for. That would look like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM favorites_table
WHERE name IN ('Sam', 'Victor', 'Cameron', 'Samantha');
```

Which would return:

| name | favorite_food |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | Sushi |
| Cameron | Pizza |
| Samantha | Burgers |
| Victor | Salad |

But let's say that instead of an array of exact matches, I want to match it to an array of substrings. I'm imagining combining a `WHERE ... IN` clause with the `LIKE` clause, something like this...?

```
SELECT *
FROM favorites_table
WHERE name IN LIKE ('am', 'ic');
```

Which would return the same results.

I know this is probably a simple task, but I'm still learning mysql, any help is appreciated <3

Comment: It is not clear enough it is for it is for mysql, or if you typed mysql as a mistake.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I'm using Postgres, and this answered my question perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264937/10637188