# how to use where + like IN in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I would like to use `like` in a `where` statement using a list like test:

```
select * 
FROM mydb.my_table.K
WHERE K.myid LIKE IN ('AT%', 'BEL%' , 'DDCY%')
```

This doees not work, while this does:

```
select * 
FROM mydb.my_table.K
WHERE (K.myid LIKE 'AT%' OR K.myid LIKE'BEL%' OR K.myid LIKE 'DDCY%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using STRLEFT?

```
select * 
FROM mydb.my_table.K
WHERE STRLEFT(K.myid,2) IN ('AT', 'BE' , 'CY')
```

Comment: nice work arround, yet it might no generalize well to more complicated string patterns, so I will leave the question up for bit

Comment: Neither is a LIKE.   FWIW, I don't think syntax exists to allow you to do what you want to do.

LIKE is for comparing strings.

IN is for checking existence in a set.  If you're hellbent on using LIKE you're going to need to dynamically build that WHERE clause.

The only issues with the solution enlisted above is that right now, it only does the first two characters.

Your never-mentioned-before "more complicated string patterns" would be additional OR clauses.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Comment: i do not this this will work ` 'CY'` to look for a pattern `DDCY%`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first SQL is syntactically correct but it will not work as per logic. Second SQL does the trick but its slow and if you have many arguments this can be a problem.

Unfortunately you can not use arguments in a list but you can use `rlike` or `regexp_like` to do the trick.

```
select * 
FROM mydb.my_table.K
WHERE K.myid RLIKE '^AT|^BEL|^DDC'
```

Please note this is a regular expression and `^` means start of a string and `|` concatenates all pattern arguments.