# SQL query with like for multiple values from comma separated string in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I want to filter by multiple values with like.

I have read the answer in below link:

[Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

The only difference I have here is I don't have values that I want to look for as stated in the answer as below:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(t.something, '"bla*" OR "foo*" OR "batz*"')
```

The values I want to query is coming from splitting a string:

```
select value from string_split(@String_With_Commas,',')
```

So how can I create the below query's second part (containing OR's) coming from the splitted string values ?

```
  WHERE CONTAINS(t.something, '"bla*" OR "foo*" OR "batz*"')
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT returns a table, does it not? So how would you formulate a query using a table? Perhaps `IN`? Do you have full-text indexing implemented on the column?

Comment: Yes but as stated in the answer I have mentioned you can't combine IN with LIKE

Comment: Yes that column is Full-text indexed

Comment: But you *can* combine `LIKE` with `EXISTS`. Though that won't use your Fulltext index.