# SQL: Multiple Column in a Table has same a condition: WHERE COL1 LIKE 'VALUE' OR COL2 LIKE 'VALUE'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem when filtering data in a table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE COL1 LIKE '%VALUE%' 
   OR COL2 LIKE '%VALUE%' 
   OR COL3 LIKE '%VALUE%'...;
```

I want to optimize this SQL statement.

I was thinking about using `WHERE IN ...` but `IN` just filters that thing exactly equal to "VALUE".

Any idea for this?

Thanks a lot.

I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE 'VALUE' IN (COL1, COL2);
```

but I expected

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE '%VALUE%' LIKE/IN (COL1,COL2);
```

Can I do that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'd rather consider a table redesign. Why do you have to search several columns?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? Is your issue performance or just the verbosity of the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a combination of "LIKE" and "IN" in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Comment: For "optimizing" I think you really mean to use fulltext search capabilities instead (check chapter 12 in documentation).

Comment: @Stephan In this case, I think "Just the verbosity of the query", lol

Comment: Then I think there is nothing to be optimized for you, maybe just replace Like with ILike or use regular expression (~).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question, you could concatenate the columns and use an array if there's multiple values you want to search for.

```
create table t1 (
  col1 text
  ,col2 text
  ,col3 text
);

insert into t1 (col1,col2,col3)
values
('foobar', 'bar', 'alpaca')
,('cat','dog','duck');

SELECT 
    *
FROM t1
WHERE (col1 ||' '|| col2 ||' '|| col3) ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['%foo%','%bar%', '%cat%'])
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e54e5eecbdc4c1374d441d6553049fbf

Unsure how performant this would be, but I believe it answers your direct question and is probably more readable than a long list of `OR` statements.

Comment: Valid, you would need to add a space between the concatenation of the columns. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @CetinBasoz thank you so much, I think this is exactly what i want. Best regards

Comment: @quyetkaito, I didn't do that, Edward Radcliffe did. Please mark it as an answer (and I still suggest you to look into chapter 12:)

Comment: @CetinBasoz okay

Comment: FYI this could lead to unexpected results if the search term has spaces. Example, if col1 has "Hello" and col2 has "World" and the user searches "Hello World", your original query would return nothing. But this query would return that record. To protect against this, probably safer to delimit with an unusual character like pipe "|" or tilde "~"