# i need to combine like and in query ..for e.g some thing like select * from table where first_name in ('%abc%','%def%')

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

i need to combine like and in query ..for e.g some thing like select * from table where first_name in ('%abc%','%def%')

select * from table where lower(first_name) like any(array['%neh%','%bip%']);

this is not working in jpa

Comment: Would `first_name like X or first_name like Y` be ok or do you need to append an arbitrary number of possibilities?

Comment: It seems that SQL itself doesn't support this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql for hints on how to work around it.

Comment: first_name like X or first_name like Y ,.......can be arbitary number of possibilities

Comment: *can be arbitary number of possibilities* Then you probably need to build your SQL string and your parameter list dynamically.

Comment: it wont take ['%neh%','%bip%'] as array if this is build dynamically

Comment: lower(u.first_name) like any(array[string_to_array(?2,',')])...dynamically building parameter list worked