# pg-promise mulitple OR in where clause

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm having some trouble with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

I would like to specify an undefined number of parameters in the `WHERE` clause.

All the parameters will be concatenated with `OR`.

```
db.any(
  'SELECT genre FROM genres'+
  'WHERE ( (genres.genre LIKE \'Animation\' OR genres.genre LIKE \'Action\') ')
  .then(function(data) {
    // success;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // error;
  });
});
```

Instead of specifying parameters one by one, I have an array of genres passed by the user.

I would like to do something like this...

```
var genres = ["Action", "Adventure", "Romantic"];   
db.any(
      'SELECT genre FROM genres'+
      'WHERE ( (genres.genre LIKE $1) '), [genres])
      .then(function(data) {
        // success;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // error;
      });
});
```

I can't find a way to make it work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `pg-promise` is all about generating whatever SQL you want. Therefore, you should include example of a **valid** final SQL that you want generated. I don't think that `LIKE $1` can result in a valid SQL in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more about PostgreSQL syntax for multiple `LIKE` usage, rather than [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). See [Combining multiple like queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245536/sql-combining-multiple-like-queries).

The easiest in your case is to use `LIKE ANY(array[...])` syntax:

```
const genres = ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Romantic'];

db.any('SELECT genre FROM genres WHERE genre LIKE ANY($1)'), [genres])
      .then(data => {
          // success, data = matching genres
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // error
      });
});
```

This will format and execute:

```
SELECT genre FROM genres WHERE genre LIKE ANY(array['Action', 'Adventure', 'Romantic'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved.
It is possible to do the same with AND operator?

Comment: @Atomos `AND` logic doesn't make sense in the context of the `LIKE` operand. So I'm not sure what you are even asking.